# How can I buy U.S.-listed stock as a South African?

Tags: stocks

How could I buy, for instance, Google stock as a South African?

Most online services I've tried requires a Social Security Number, which I don't have. Most local trading firms simply don't support anything but the JSE.

Suggestions?

Comment: Certain South African-based brokers may offer offshore/foreign investments trading, giving you access to world exchanges beyond the JSE. Have you looked into this possibility?

Comment: I have struck out on three so far. Will keep looking. :)

Comment: Try googling `site:.za offshore trading` and see what comes up. Be sure to DYODD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Foreigner can use [ITIN](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/Individual-Taxpayer-Identification-Number-%28ITIN%29) in lieu of SSN to open US bank accounts.

If there's no local broker at all in your own country that allows trading in the US (which I seriously doubt...), you'll have to go through the tedious and problematic procedure to issue an ITIN, or open a trading account in person next time you visit the US (and then it will be very limited with what you can do if you don't have a tax ID).

Comment: I'll make some more phone calls. Are there online options - generic, multiple stock exchange type trading platforms?

Comment: @MeagerMouse what do you mean by "generic multiple stock exchange type trading platforms"?

Comment: an online service where I can trade stocks listed on multiple stock exchanges.

Comment: Sure, plenty. Etrade, TD, Fidelity, Scottrade...

Comment: I'll look into those, I'm pretty sure the 4 I've tried already ask for SSN. I'll read up on ITINs in the meantime. Thanks.